# Does Yii validation Scenarios work with enableClientValidation set to true?

Tags: yii

Using Yii 1.1.8 here.

Does anyone know if Yii validation scenarios work with client side Yii validation `'enableClientValidation'=>true` ?

Comment: This is a really good question! You should try it in a Yii demo with a really simple form and som simple rules!

Comment: @darkheir - imagine you have a form where the user  can choose either to publish a record or only insert it. That checkbox should trigger the scenario. I'm not sure however, how to make that (perhaps needed) ajax call in order to test this. I will however try to figure it out and shared here.

Answer (score 0):

Yii will use the scenario that was set up when you built the form.

So whatever the scenario was when the form was initialized will be honoured as the ActiveForm uses [Model->getValidators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getValidators-detail).

Only problem with this is incase the scenario changes on your "save" logic, but that shouldn't be too common.