# Disable validation in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-events

I am trying to implement a "Save as Draft" functioning in my project using Yii. I have a form with 2 buttons :- Submit and Save . On clicking the Submit button , after validating  all the fields including required fields the form data is saved into the database. It works perfect. On clicking Save button I need to save the form data without default validations into the database. How can I implement this disabling of validation in a controller action ?? 
All advices are acceptable..
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turning off validation rules all together is easy:

```
$model->save(false);
```

This will not do any validation and will just try and save your model (may still fail on the database side).

But if you want to run *some* validation ,you might want to look into [**Scenarios** here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/). They allow you to specify a different set of rules depending on which scenario you initialize the model with. That way you can only turn on/off whole sets of validation rules.

```
$model = new Thingy();
$model->save(); // All default validation rules

$model = new Thingy('draft');
$model->save(); //Applies all default & "draft" validation rules
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with client side validation? I have a similar problem as the OP. Server-side, it's simple enough to not validate when I don't need to validate, but if client-side validation is enabled, clicking either button causes it to validate. Can I set the scenario on button-press somehow?

Comment: I don't work with Yii much anymore and wasn't sure of the answer to that one. So i did some searching and found myself answering the question, guess I should remember what I learn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390220/does-yii-validation-scenarios-work-with-enableclientvalidation-set-to-true

So in short. No, only the scenario the form is built with will be used. Unless this has changed in Yii core since then.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says in Controller but as far as I know, in controller we have filters which do for example check the permissions. That can be overridden as explained in [this section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) of the guide. If you meant the validation that is done in model, then you can use scenarios (bypass validation by binding rules to scenario and no validation in other scenarios).
Check [this thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20141-solved-how-can-i-skip-a-validation-rule-on-a-specific-case/) that discuss a like problem

If I have misunderstood your question please comment here so that I update the answer accordingly!